# How can I use variables that I have imported?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import variables from another module. My wish is to use the "import module" way not the "from x import y" way. 
The import line works, but I get an error when trying to print variables from the source module.

I have an empty *init*.py file; All files init, module1 and module2 are in the same folder. The folder is seen in sys.path.
Using from x import y works. I wanna use just import module. 
What am I missing?

**module1.py:**

```
X=8
List=[8,2,9]
ListOfStrings=["Champa","Lampa", "Dampa"]
All=[X, List, ListOfStrings, String]

print(All)\
```

**module2.py:**

```
import module1
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)

print(X)
```

module1 is run but X shows as not defined.

**Result:**

```
[8, [8, 2, 9], ['Champa', 'Lampa', 'Dampa'], 'This is a string']
theactualpath\Desktop\Work Excercises\py_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "theactualpath\Desktop\Work Excercises\py_test\module2.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(X)
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "theactualpath\Desktop\Work\Excercises\py_test\module2.py"]
[dir: theactualpath\Desktop\Work Excercises\py_test]
[path: various paths from my computer, not the current working folder thou]
```

Comment: you have not imported  `module1`

Comment: @Netwave I did, sorry I had a problem formatting the question here and the first line did not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives.

Reference the module1 namespace:

```
import module1
...
print(module1.X)
```

Bring everything (or just whatever you need) from module1 into your module2 namespace:

```
from module1 import * # or just import  whatever you need: from module1 import X
...
print(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.

After importing the module `import module1`, the variable `X` is bound to the module's namespace, thus you have to replace

```
print (X)
```

with

```
print (module1.X)
```

Your first example (`print (X)`) would print the variable `X` from the current file and not from the module.

Comment: thanks for the welcome and clarifications! glad to be here

Answer (score 0):

Using `print(X)` is wrong. You must use `print(module1.X)`